# Getting paste from specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, user, paste

i want to copy a range starting from cell B to Cell N in columms but in Rows it can go to even 1000 i want a macro that start pasting any data from B:10 and nowhere else.P.S. The data is dynamic which is viewable to user based on their Id Password.

```
Sub Portfolio()
'
' Portfolio Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[CRN]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:= _
        "TRUE"
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$10:$N$1000"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"
    Range("Table2[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[CRN]]").Select
End Sub
```

I have  created this macro but when I gave my pointer on  any other cell cell and not on B:10 data starts copying from there.

Comment: So, what have you tried sofar to achieve what you want? Please note that Superuser is not code writing service. You are supposed to show what effort you have put into solving the problem you have. You can read more about asking in [how to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have done changes u can check @Tom Brunberg

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

> ... I want a macro that start pasting any data from B:10 and nowhere else.

To achieve that add the line

```
Range("B10").Select
```

just before

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

It will force the pasting to start at `B10`.